# Validation error not getting localized string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, localization

I'm having an issue with a validation error in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I've applied a `RegularExpression` rule for a field which will accept only numeric input. Should the data contain any other character it should display an error message.

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.General), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CodeMustBeNumeric")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```

Problem is, no matter what's the current culture setting, it always displays the default resource and not the localized one. Some more details to follow.

My resources:

[image: My resources:]

[image: General resource]

[image]

The result:

[image]

As you can see, the current culture for all strings is Italian, but not for the validation error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I was doing something wrong and there was an out-of-the-box way to solve this, but with a deeper search I found out the common solution is just creating a custom validation attribute which inhreits from the ASP.NET one.

So I did, and it works fine. Should anyone need it, here it is:

```
public class CustomRegularExpressionAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        string currentLang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(currentLang);
        return HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(ErrorMessageResourceType.Name.ToString(), ErrorMessageResourceName, ci).ToString();
    }

    public CustomRegularExpressionAttribute(string pattern)
        : base(pattern)
    {

    }
}
```

And the new call:

```
[CustomRegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.General), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CodeMustBeNumeric")]
public string Code { get; set; }
```